# What are some "derivative notations" worth to memorize? Like $\frac{x''}{x'}$ is equal to $\left(\ln\left(x'\right)\right)'$ (x depends on t)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, soft-question, differential

It can make the calculation easier especially in differential equations but I only know this and $-\frac{x'}{x^2}$ = $\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)'$

Answer (score 0):

A few that immediately come to mind are:
$$\begin{gather}
ydx+xdy = d(xy) \\
\frac{ydx-xdy}{y^2} = d\left(\frac xy\right) \\
\frac{ydx+xdy}{xy} = d(\ln(xy)) \\
\frac{ydx-xdy}{xy} = d\left(\ln\left(\frac xy\right)\right) \\
\frac{ydx+xdy}{1+x^2y^2} = d(\arctan (xy))
\end{gather}$$